# #error when compiling flutter app from codemagic

Tags: ios, flutter, runner, codemagic

When I am going to compile flutter project to ios from CodeMagic, then build failed with this error.

```
 Xcode's output:
 ↳
 error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
1) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/builder/clone/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to '/Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi, can you check this thread https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685

Comment: @Mikhail But this is in codemagic. So there's no way to open xcode and select such a settings. And tried with that settings under immediate solution. Entering key value in the runner info.plist. but still this error come

Comment: you can use VNC access to builder machine if you have no macOS computer https://docs.codemagic.io/troubleshooting/accessing-builder-machine-via-ssh/

Comment: It can open and yes I can work on xcode but when the build fail in the site, it automatically close the ssh connection also. How can I solve that?

Comment: Is there any way to do that from fluter or ios runner info.plist something

Comment: were you able to fix the error? also, the issue with VNC/SSH connection was fixed and now you should have 20 minutes to check build machine.

Comment: With that I coudn't solve. I did that task using my friend's mac. Thank you